# Ubuntu will not update from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: updates, 13.10

I've tried both terminal and software updater.

According to Terminal I have no update.

I will click on Software Updater and it will show that an update to 13.10 is available, but after I click upgrade and enter my credentials the window will simply close and no subsequent window will pop up. I've never had this issue before. I've restarted multiple times and it's still the same issue.

Anybody else having this problem? If so has anybody figured out a fix?

Any help is appreciated. I've checked the software and update settings. Everything seemed okay. Restored defaults but the problem persisted.

Again, any help is appreciated.

(:

Comment: Dunno how the 50 ended up on there, disregard.

Answer (score 1):

So when you type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` you get nothing and no errors? Have you ensure you have done a `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update` before typing dist-upgrade?

Also you can do `sudo do-release-upgrade` which will check for new versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Or he can just make a bootable and upgrade using the GUI